# Preventing Application Closure

Tags: windows-xp

I'm a self employed software developer whose only computer has a single monitor. The problem I have is that I often have many windows open and will frequently close the wrong window when cleaning up the desktop. Is there a free tool available that will prevent user defined applications from being closed by the user?

Comment: Please tag your question with the OS.

Comment: who's the genious that put the 'maximize' button right next to the 'close' button?

Answer (score 2):

Havn't heard of one, however if you're just alt tabbing perhaps you should use the microsoft power toy "Virtual Desktop Monitor".  It won't prevent you from closing the programs but if you put the important ones on one desktop and just switch to another for the lesser important ones you should accomplish the same thing.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

Comment: This is of course assuming you're using XP.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a hotkey program ([Auto Hot Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is often mentioned) to over-ride alt-F4, but I don't know of any way to remove the 'close' box from the window.